# Problems installing UR driver on ROS kinetic

Tags: ros, driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I'm having trouble installing the [ur_robot_driver](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver). I've followed all the steps for installing ROS kinetic and it installed alright and now that I am trying to install the drivers for UR robots an error appears whenever I try running the "rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y":

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ur_kinematics: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_ros_planning]
ur10e_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur5e_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur10_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur_calibration: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ur_client_library]
ur5_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
controller_stopper: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [controller_manager_msgs]
ur_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [position_controllers] 
ur_robot_driver: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ur_msgs]
ur_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [joint_state_publisher_gui]
ur3_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur16e_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur3e_moveit_config: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [moveit_simple_controller_manager]
ur_controllers: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [realtime_tools]
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382809/problems-installing-ur-driver-on-ros-kinetic/) by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinetic ist EOL (End of Life). That means you have to run the following command before `rosdep install`:

```
rosdep update --include-eol-distros
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2021-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-07-21**:
Thanks! I tried that and the rosdep install command worked afterwards, but when I tried running the catkin_make command I got this:

```
Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/src/hardware_interface.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/src/hardware_interface.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8600: recipe for target 'Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/CMakeFiles/ur_robot_driver_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

The message was longer but I can't paste it in here entirely.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2021-07-21**:
Please post the full error message somewhere, e.g. pastebin.com or github gist.

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-07-21**:
Ok. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/i82L0kdr

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-21**:
Here are the important lines:

```
In file included from /home/danielh/catkin_ws/src/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/src/urcl_log_handler.cpp:32:0:
/home/danielh/catkin_ws/src/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_robot_driver/include/ur_robot_driver/urcl_log_handler.h:43:31: error: ‘urcl’ has not been declared
 class UrclLogHandler : public urcl::LogHandler
```

Looks like you are trying to use a ros2 driver on ros1. That's not going to ever work.

**Comment by [fexner](https://answers.ros.org/users/26760/fexner/) on 2021-07-22**:
Nope, this looks like the ros1 driver. Note, that kinetic is not supported anymore by the driver, so it might not be possible to get it running on ROS kinetic.

Nevertheless, you will need the ur_client_library (urcl) for this driver to work. As it is not released for kinetic in recent versions, you might want to consider building that from source, as well, as described [here](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#alternative-all-source-build).

**Comment by [horvath.daniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/75585/horvath.daniel/) on 2021-07-22**:
I tried building it from source and it gave me another error: https://pastebin.com/racxf8Kg
I'll try installing it on another version of ros. Is melodic supported by the driver?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-22**:
@fexner thank you for correction. I should not have guessed.